# Online UPS: Saving Power with solar panels

Tags: solar-energy, ups

We have a 300kW online UPS for a data center.
An AC/DC converter converts mains to DC, which is used to charge 2 x 50 12V batteries (50 connected in series each) and at the same time feed the DC/AC converter to power the load.

The plan is now to install a (quite large) number of solar panels.
The question is: Would it be possible to directly feed the DC from the panels to the DC/AC converter of the UPS (in parallel to the batteries and the AC/DC converter)?

Can it be made sure, that indeed the DC power from the solar panels is used and not the power from the AC/DC converter from the line?

This would be more efficient compared to trying to feed the AC/DC converter of the UPS.
We have also thought about feeding the load directly, but then another AC/DC converter would be necessary, which we would like to avoid.

Comment: Theoretically yes; in reality maybe; but when you're dealing with this amount of energy surely the manufacturer is helping you with this project because you are spending a lot of money. *Ask them*. (More specifically, ask the UPS guys)

Comment: Yes to all your questions, but you need an MPPT converter between the solar panels and the UPS. Dunno why everyone's so scared of 300kW. That's a typical data center UPS and doesn't need special considerations. Guess some people live their life on breadboards and 1A current limits lol

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, you might be able to directly use the solar cells's DC to supply your UPS' DC voltage.

However:

Your solar cells probably won't be producing the same voltage throughout the day, and the voltage will sharply fluctuate under load; that's why you typically find a DC/DC converter in scenarios where a solar cell supplies something that needs a constant voltage.

It's thoroughly possible that a DC/DC converter that doesn't need great regulation since it's only used to supply a voltage that just needs to be slightly higher than your current battery bank's output voltage is more efficient than having a nice sinusoidal DC/AC converter, followed by an AC/DC downconverter.

However, this is high-power stuff, as in: do a mistake and you'll explode things, blind people nearby and weld whatever catches the spark to whatever fixes it to the dirt. You'll need to consult with the companies that have experience with building solar power "inverters" (DC/AC converters), as I'm pretty sure your use case is not at all unique – charging batteries with solar is a standard application, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be more efficient to directly feed the batteries but the UPS must support that. You also need to have a solar charge controller which is essentially a DC to DC converter that tracks the power from the solar panels.

So what would be more efficient you would need different equipment